# editing Devise RegistrationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am on rails 4 with the latest devise gem as far as I know therefore it does not automatically create a Registrations Controller that is viewable in the Controllers folder.

So as far as I understand you can make your own that will extend onto the hidden one. that's what I did when I made this so that the user gets redirected somewhere:

registrations_controller.rb

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    edit_profile_path(current_user.id)
  end

end
```

That works great.

Then I decided I wanted to change what happens when they destroy their account. so I copied some code into my controller and edited it slightly: (copied from https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb)

```
def destroy
  resource.destroy
  Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name)
  set_flash_message :notice, :destroyed if is_flashing_format?
  yield resource if block_given?
  respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to after_sign_out_path_for(resource_name), notice: "THIS EDIT IS WORKING" }
end
```

However, This didn't work. all I did was add the notice: on to the end of the redirect but it gave me this error when I signed in and "clicked cancel my account":

> Unknown action The action 'destroy' could not be found for
>   RegistrationsController

weird right? thats the entire text of the error.

what am I doing wrong? or more importantly how do I add code that gets executed during the destroy registrations function?

UPDATE:

further troubleshooting revealed that simplifying the code to this returns same results:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    edit_profile_path(current_user.id)
  end

  def destroy
        redirect_to root_path, notice: "Sadly, this isn't working."
  end

end
```

Comment: I don't know what spring is

Comment: rails preloader, caching the rails process. stop rails server and run `spring stop`

Comment: https://github.com/rails/spring

Comment: I tried that but got the same result

Comment: `#destroy` is not under `protected` keyword?

Answer (score 0):

ok, this fixed it but I'm not sure its the most secure option, let me know in the comments if there is a better way.

All I had to do is move def destroy out from under protected. (I don't know what that means practically speaking, but it works).

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def destroy
    resource.destroy
    Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name)
    set_flash_message :notice, :destroyed if is_flashing_format?
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to "http://google.com" }
  end

  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    edit_profile_path(current_user.id)
  end

end
```